# Implement jQuery on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to integrate two jQuery scripts into one but because the elements of the first part are created dynamically using jQuery I can't get the second part of the project working.

**The project:**

1.Instagram pictures are parsed as JSON into `li` elements.

Here's a portion of the code:

```
<ul id="elasticstack" class="elasticstack">
</ul>

<script>
$("#elasticstack").append("<li><div class='peri-pic'><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /><span class='name'>"+ data.data[i].caption.from.username +"</span> <span class='likes'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span><p>"+data.data[i].likes.count +"</p></span></div></li>"
    );  
</script>
```

Source: [LINK](http://stuffthatspins.com/stuff/instagram-user-hashtag-stream-display/)

2.This works fine but when I try to add the slider none of the functions work. Even if I wrap the callout function in a `$( document ).ready(function() { });`

Here's the call out code:

```
<script>
    new ElastiStack( document.getElementById( 'elasticstack' ) );
</script>
```

Source: [LINK](http://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticStack/)

Here's the JS Fiddle with all my code: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/b5qwghbr/)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Don't create the `ElastiStack` until the images have been appended to the DOM.

Comment: @Mathletics how do I do that?

Comment: Hm. I don't think it is good idea mixing pure js with jQuery

Comment: @bksi that's a very good point. I imagined there'd be some sort of conflict. I've never mixed them before.

Comment: did you try to use $("#elasticstack") instead document.getElementById...?

Comment: @bksi I just tried it and it's still not working. Thanks though

Comment: @bksi are you (and the person who upvoted that comment) joking? _mixing pure js with jQuery_? What do you think jQuery _is_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this. After the initial `loadImages(start_url)` call, you should be able to call `loadImages(next_url)` to load and display more. `new ElastiStack` had to be called after the images had been appended.

```
var access_token = "18360510.5b9e1e6.de870cc4d5344ffeaae178542029e98b",
    user_id = "18360510", //userid
    start_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+user_id+"/media/recent/?access_token="+access_token,
    next_url;

function loadImages(url){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        success: function(data){
            displayImages(data);
            next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
        }
    })
}

function displayImages(images){
    for(var i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if(images.data[i]){
            $("#elasticstack").append("<li><img class='instagram-image' src='" + images.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "'></li>");
        }
    }

    // Call it after the images have been appended
    new ElastiStack(document.getElementById('elasticstack'));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    loadImages(start_url);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the `ElastiStack` after data (`HTML` elements) has been appended into the `DOM` in your `ajax`, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   // ...
    $("#elasticstack").append(...);
}

new ElastiStack(...);
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: url ,
            success: function(data) {

            next_url = data.pagination.next_url;
            //count = data.data.length;
            //three rows of four
            count = 20; 

            //uncommment to see da codez
            //console.log("count: " + count );
            //console.log("next_url: " + next_url );
            //console.log("data: " + JSON.stringify(data) );

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (typeof data.data[i] !== 'undefined' ) {
                    //console.log("id: " + data.data[i].id);
                        $("#elasticstack").append("<li><img class='instagram-image' src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></li>"
                    );  
                    }  
            }     
            new ElastiStack(document.getElementById('elasticstack'));
        }
    });
```

You have to move your `new ElastiStack(document.getElementById('elasticstack'));` inside the ajax success event. You don't have to change anything else in your. I also updated your JSFiddle.